# .NET Core MVC POST to action not deserializing into model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make my .net core MVC website receive JSON that I send from a view through javascript. Sadly it seems the model is not being filled in with the data.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSubtitles(AddSubtitleSettingsModel model)
{
    /* do things and save to database */
    return RedirectToAction("Subtitling");
}
```

My model:

```
public class AddSubtitleSettingsModel
{
    public HashSet<string> from { get; set; }
    public HashSet<string> to { get; set; }
    public decimal startupRateLessThanOneMinute { get; set; }
    public decimal startupRateBetweenOneAndThreeMinutes { get; set; }
    public decimal pricePerSubtitle { get; set; }
    public decimal defaultRateTranslators { get; set; }
}
```

Request being sent to POST action:
[image: Request]

I can tell the model is not being filled in because I put a breakpoint inside the action and I checked model, and everything was null/empty:
[image: Model empty]

This is how I send my request from the javascript:

```
let fromValues: any = fromLanguages.getValue();
let toValues: any = toLanguages.getValue();
var data = {
    from: fromValues.map((l: any) => l.value),
    to: toValues.map((l: any) => l.value),
    startupRateLessThanOneMinute: Number($('#srLt1m').val()),
    startupRateBetweenOneAndThreeMinutes: Number($('#stBt13m').val()),
    startupRateBetweenThreeAndFiveMinutes: Number($('#stBt35m').val()),
    pricePerSubtitle: Number($('#pPS').val()),
    defaultRateTranslators: Number($('#dRT').val())
}

fetch('/Settings/AddSubtitles', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then((response: any) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `[FromBody]` to your Method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSubtitles([FromBody]AddSubtitleSettingsModel model)
{
    /* do things and save to database */
    return RedirectToAction("Subtitling");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue.